# A simple approach to Infinite Scroll MySql Pulls

Tags: javascript, mysql, jquery

I'm having difficulty iterating through records while scrolling window. My initial thought was to load enough records to fit on screen then load an additional set when window scrolled to bottom. I've tried using session / variables to pass some counter to a function, no luck. The code below returns enough records to fit window height but with 0,10 limit. What would be a simple method to resolve this?

Another question is should I use LIMIT or ID > + LIMIT on the Mysql query?

```
$(function(){

setInterval(function(){

var totalHeight, currentScroll, visibleHeight;

if (document.documentElement.scrollTop)
{ currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop; }
else
{ currentScroll = document.body.scrollTop; }

totalHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
visibleHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

if (totalHeight <= currentScroll + visibleHeight )
  {

    $.get('infinite_pull.php', function(data) {
      $('body').append(data);
      //alert('Load was performed.');
    });

  }
  else
  {
  $('.dd').css('background-color','white');
  }  
            }
, 100);

});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('project5');

    $query = "select user_email from users limit 0,10;";
    $results= mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){ 
        echo $row['0'] . '<br/>';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to call the php file multiple times sound bad,
all that overhead proberly worse then getting all at once.
can't you just calculate how many you need, and ask for that number?

```
<?php
    $from = (int) $_GET['from'];
    $count = (int) $_GET['count'];

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('project5');

    $query = "select user_email from users limit {$from},{$count};";
    $results= mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){ 
        echo $row['0'] . '<br/>';
    }

?>
```

i also think you should add an order by, to be sure the result always gets in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT`, which combines a offset (1st param) and number of rows to get (2nd param). Here's a short example of pagination that get's the 7th page of a 100 numbers 7 at a time.

```
<?php

$arr = array();
for ( $x = 0; $x < 100; $x += 1 ) {
    $arr[] = $x;
};

$page = 7;
$per_page = 7;
$current_page = 1;

for ( $z = 0; $z < count( $arr ); $z += 1 ) {
    if ( 0 === ( $z % $per_page ) ) {
        $current_page += 1;
    }
    if ( $current_page === $page ) {
        $num_results = $current_page * $per_page;
        $query = "select user_email from users limit {$num_results},{$per_page};";
        echo "value $z on page $page via $query \n";
    }
}


?>
```

Output:

```
$ php pagination.php 
value 35 on page 7 via select user_email from users limit 49,7; 
value 36 on page 7 via select user_email from users limit 49,7; 
value 37 on page 7 via select user_email from users limit 49,7; 
value 38 on page 7 via select user_email from users limit 49,7; 
value 39 on page 7 via select user_email from users limit 49,7; 
value 40 on page 7 via select user_email from users limit 49,7; 
value 41 on page 7 via select user_email from users limit 49,7;
```